# Visual Studio | Window layer grid

Tags: visual-studio, layout, grid, window, atom-editor

I just signed up on this site because I think here are the most qualified people for answering my questions. Maybe someday I can answer some too :)

```
<p>Hello, Stackoverflow!</p>
```

**Here is my question:**

There are many beautiful IDE's like Atom or Sublimetext where you can adjust your window layer just like you want. Now, i find trouble in Visual Studio doing this.

**Here is a preview how it should look like (Atom)**
[This is my favourite layout and i want this to be in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1yog.png)

So, is it possible? Maybe with an extension or even a built in function?

Comment: This layout is not possible in VS. You can make two (or more) horizontal or vertical pane for code. But you cannot split further a code pane.

Comment: Ok! @apr And there is not even a extension for this?